# Using Visual Studio to develop a hybrid app with cordova

Tags: node.js, cordova, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-cordova

I've been trying to get set up with Cordova to play around with building a hybrid app in VS 2012.

But, I'm confused about the integration between Cordova and VS. I've got all the tools (VS2012 SP2, Node.js Tools, Cordova from npm, and I also downloaded the Cordova zip package).

My questions are:

- I only seem to find Windows Phone project templates in the Cordova folder. If I used this, would the application I build automatically work on iOS and Android, too? If not, how do I go about getting the app up and running with the different platforms? Whats with the specific 'Windows Phone' template on a multi-platform solution?
- How do I test the application on say, iOS, if I'm developing it on a Windows OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using Cordova for around a year now through the multi-device hybrid support added in Visual Studio 2013s Update 2. There is a config.xml file that you edit to push the app to different devices. Download the update and take a look at this tutorial:
[Multi-device hybrid app tutorial](http://blog.falafel.com/Blogs/GeorgeSaadeh/george-saadeh/2014/05/14/getting-started-with-cordova-and-multi-device-hybrid-app-in-visual-studio)